# Google Analytics e-commerce tracking with initial not last referrer

Tags: google-analytics

We have shareware product with 30 days trial period. Our product has a webinterface so users access it in a browser by typing `http://localhost or http://192.168.1.XXX.`

Usually customers come from organic search or referal sites, download the product, use it for 30 days. After that a license alert is shown, so customers click on a Buy button, go to the site and buy the product.

Google Analytics e-commerce tracking is implemented on the site and we get all transaction reports.

But reports are not right. Referrer source for purchase is usually local ip and time to purchase is less than 1 day. But it is not right.

Is it possible to track real first entrance referrer and real time to purchase?

Answer (score 1):

gv0zd,

be aware that **Google Analytics measure devices, not real users**. So if somebody starts a trial from one computer, and then somebody else (probably sitting in the purchasing department) comes to your website and converts, this will be reported as a new visitor with different visit source and time-to-purchase of 1 day. Bad for reporting, but technologically correct.

Have you tried [MultiChannel Funnel reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1191180?hl=en)? They might be helpful.

There is an ongoing discussion how to attributed the credit correctly, but I am afraid the complexity of this issue is too much for a thread here. For an introduction, I suggest your start with this [brilliant article by Avinash](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/multi-channel-attribution-definitions-models/).

However, consider storing the first visit source to custom dimension/custom variable and always store the last one into a different slot. Also, solutions like [DirectMonster from LunaMetrics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/10/02/direct-monster-fix-dark-social/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=%28opu%20qspwjefe%29&ts=1389037600) could increase the accuracy for your particular case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: MultiChannel Funnel reports work properly but they don't give any information about referrer. This information is vital for advertising planning

Comment: You can -- both SOURCE and MEDIUM dimensions are available (Assisted Conversions report).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'd found it just before your answered:) But it's only Assisted source not really initial.

Comment: If you switch to First-Interaction Analysis (top part of the page, just below Explorer tab), you should get the number you need. You can also create a segment, that will include only visits with first interaction being referral and then start doing some magic :-)